# Passing Strings into Structures

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I apologize if I've already answered my own question or if I'm not using the correct terminology.  I'm attempting to pass a string to a pointer structure.  I know what I'm attempting to do works, when I use strcpy(structure->item[number], "abc"); however, I'm unable to assign data to the structure, using structure->item[number]="abc".  I've tried *structure->item[number]="abc", *structure->item[number]={"abc"}, and structure->item={"abc"}; none of them work - for most the compiler will reject the syntax.  I assume you could also use a getch() loop to handle passing the characters into the pointer structure, although it could be a bit tedious that way.

**What is the best way to pass strings into pointer arrays and why can't I assign them using the structure->item[number]="abc" syntax?**  I know that gets() works, but I don't know if it's the best way.  My code is attached below.  It's possible the first iteration of the structure has a syntax error I'm missing as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct car
{
    char model[50];
};

int main()
{
    struct car * num[3];
    num[0]=(struct car *)malloc(3*sizeof(struct car *));
    *num[0]->model="Lambo";    //This doesn't pull the detail in
    puts(num[0]->model);        //Garbage created
    strcpy(num[0]->model, "Lambo");  //This works
    puts(num[0]->model);    //Shows up fine
    free(num[0]);
}
```

Comment: because `model` is a buffer. You cannot assign it, you have to copy into it.

Comment: “I know that gets() works..." No. Stop right there. Never use `gets()`. In fact `gets()` has been removed from modern C standards (since C11).

Comment: ASIDE: [small help with malloc()](https://godbolt.org/z/dzrWbozhG)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone - I really appreciate it!  C is a bit strange in terms of strings.  strcpy() is then the best way to name a bunch of pointer-string structures?  Thank you for the malloc update - I forgot malloc outputs as a character.  Also, went overboard and accidentally allocated 3 * car, instead of using 1 structure for the 1 space in the array.